# Getting sender on a dynamically created NSButton checkbox

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, selector, nsbutton

I'm programmatically creating NSTableViewCells and adding and NSButton with checkbox as a subview to some of them. How can I get the sender that is triggering the selector when the checkbox is toggled? This is what I have working so far, but everything I've tried in order to get the sender has been unsuccessful.

```
func addCheckBox(cell: NSTableCellView){
    let checkbox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: text, target: Any?.self, action: #selector(selector))
    checkbox.setButtonType(NSButton.ButtonType.onOff)
    cell.addSubview(checkbox)

}

@objc func selector(){
    print("selector selected")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

let mainWindow: NSWindow = {
    let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(300, 300, 700, 700), styleMask: .resizable, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.isOpaque = true
    window.styleMask.insert(.miniaturizable)
    window.styleMask.insert(.titled)
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    window.title = "My Playground"
    window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    return window
}()

lazy var tableView : NSTableView = {
    let tableView = NSTableView()
    let column = NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Sample Column"))
    tableView.addTableColumn(column)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    return tableView
}()

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    mainWindow.contentView = tableView
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}}
```

extension AppDelegate: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let rowView = NSView()

    let button = NSButton()
    button.bezelStyle = .texturedRounded
    button.setButtonType(.switch)
    button.target = self
    button.action = #selector(selectorName(_:))
    button.title = "\(row)th view"
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    rowView.addSubview(button)
    return rowView
}

@objc func selectorName(_ sender: NSButton)
{
    print("The state of \(sender.title) is \(sender.state)")
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `target` to `self`

   ```
   let checkbox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: text, target: self, action: #selector(selector))
   ```
2. Use the syntax passing one parameter

   ```
   @objc func selector(_ sender : NSButton){
       print("selector selected", sender.state)
   }
   ```

Comment: It compiles, but with the parameter added selector doesn't seem to get called. edit: After I looked at mouseymaniac's example, I figured out where I got lost. I think this code does work correctly as well.